# Assign serial number to observations in SAS

Tags: sas

I have a dataset with variables as ID and Diagnosis. I want to assign serial numnber to diagnosis based on ID.
For eg: If ID 1 has 5 diagnosis, I want serial numbers to be (1, 2, 3, 4,5) and then if ID 2 has 3 diagnosis, the serial numbers would be (1, 2,3) and so on.

Is there a way to do that in SAS?
Thanks so much.

HI Thank you so much for replying. I actually want it like this.

```
Obs    diagnosis     id    diagnosis_serial_number

 1     XX             1    1
 2     XX1            1    2
 3     XX2            1    3
 4     XX3            1    4
 5     XX4            1    5
 6     XX             2    1
 7     XX1            2    2
 8     XX2            2    3
```

Comment: Do you want to know how to add a column to SAS data set?

Comment: Yes, a column which has serial numbers for diagnosis. For eg: some column like diag_serial_number which has serial number for diagnosis based on different ID Numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nupur, if you need to have the serial number for each diagnosis, then try the following:

```
proc sort data=temp;
   by id diagnosis;
run;

data temp_serial_number;
   set temp;
   by id diagnosis;
   format diagnosis_serial_number $30.;
   retain diagnosis_serial_number count;
   if first.id then do;
      count = 0;
      diagnosis_serial_number = "(";
   end;
   count + 1;
   diagnosis_serial_number = trim(left(diagnosis_serial_number)) || trim(left(count));
   if last.id then do;
      diagnosis_serial_number = trim(left(diagnosis_serial_number)) || ")";
      output;
   end;
   else do;
      diagnosis_serial_number = trim(left(diagnosis_serial_number)) || ",";
   end;
   drop diagnosis count;
run;

data temp;
   merge temp(in=in_temp) temp_serial_number(in=in_serial_nbr);
   by id;
   if in_temp then output;
run;

proc print data=temp;
run;
```

The output would look like:

```
Obs    diagnosis     id    diagnosis_serial_number

 1     XX             1    (1,2,3,4,5)
 2     XX1            1    (1,2,3,4,5)
 3     XX2            1    (1,2,3,4,5)
 4     XX3            1    (1,2,3,4,5)
 5     XX4            1    (1,2,3,4,5)
 6     XX             2    (1,2,3)
 7     XX1            2    (1,2,3)
 8     XX2            2    (1,2,3)
```

Comment: @ Hi RWill, I just made made a table in my original question of how I want it to look like. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a little unclear on exactly what you're asking for, but I think this might do the trick.  It uses a retain statement and an increment step to make a counter variable called `serial`, and uses by group processing to reset the counter each time a new ID group is found.

Note that your input dataset (called `input_ds` here) must first be sorted by ID before using this code.

```
data output_ds;
    retain serial;
    set input_ds;
    by ID;
    if first.ID then serial = 0;
    serial = serial + 1;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

Nupur, to get the output you just described, then try this:

```
proc sort data=temp;
   by id diagnosis;
run;

data temp;
   set temp;
   by id diagnosis;
   retain diagnosis_serial_number 0;
   if first.id then do;
      diagnosis_serial_number = 0;
   end;
   diagnosis_serial_number + 1;
run;
```